# Jupyter Nbextensions Configurator does not load

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

I have just installed

`Jupyter Nbextensions`

via `pip` on `Windows 10`, using the following command:

```
pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
```

Unfortunately, the page

http://localhost:8888/nbextensions/

shows as empty. Any solution for that?

Comment: & How did you installed that...can you attach the the `pip command` along with `Question`?

Comment: Thanks, @Bhargav! I have meanwhile included the used command `pip`.

Comment: `pip install jupyter contrib nbextension install --user` Try this @PaulS

Comment: Thanks, @Bhargav, but no progress after reinstalled it as you suggested.

Comment: https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/issues/1196 I've tried this ...It worked

Comment: Thanks, @Bhargav. Is that needed to install anaconda?

Comment: Haven't you installed?...I think Jupyer notebook will be inside anaconda right?...have u installed Jupyter notebook separatly?

Comment: I have installed everything with `pip`, @Bhargav.

Comment: My Windows 10 machine is a virtual one (VirtualBox). I suspect there is a conflict, as now Jupyter Notebooks that was working fine on Linux is not working at all...

Comment: Now, the Linux installation of Jupyter extensions is running well. However, the problem on the Windows 10 virtual machine persists -- I had to manually enabled all extensions I need, one by one.